# Vuetify v-data-table slot item and item.data-table-select use same time

Tags: vuetify.js

I need to use slot #item for custom UI

```
<v-data-table
  v-model="selected"
  :headers="header"
  :items="result"
  show-select    // <---- here
>
  <template v-slot:item="{ item }">   // <---- here
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.id }}</td>           
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

But after use item slot, I can't not use row select(v-data-table component's props show-select).

The row in the table, checkbox is not work anymore.

Does v-data-table is some limitation that row select can't work when use slot #item?

https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-2-forked-5l0yu0?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: No, you can't use both slots because `item` slot will replace the whole row. You should use specific `item.*` slots **or** generic `item` slot. In your case there are 2 options: write your own show-select replacement in first `<td>` tag or use only `item.*` slots. It depends on your purposes.